# Table without lines

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want to build a table but it is specific. Can u guys help me with that problem?

[image: Table1,2]

I know I have to use table and tabular, but I don't know how to put the dashes under dataset and under n=1 and so on.

And I don't want to have those grey and white background colors in the table, because I don't know :P.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,fleqn]{article} 
 \usepackage[left=30mm,right=40mm,top=25mm,bottom=20mm, includeheadfoot]    
  {geometry}%centering hinter headfoot
 \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
 \usepackage[rm={tabular, lining},sf={tabular, lining},tt={monowidth, tabular,  
   lining}]{cfr-lm}
  \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}     
 \pagestyle{myheadings}
 \usepackage{courier}
  \renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %Schriftart geändert
    \usepackage{booktabs}

 \begin{document}
  \begin{table}[htbp]
 \centering
   \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccc}
 Data set-1 for the example problem\\
 \midrule
 1& \
 1&0&&&1&4&&1&6\
  \end{tabular}
  \label{default}
 \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't want alternating colours?

Comment: @Bernard its hard for me to build the table even without alternating colors-.-

Comment: you only need the `table` environment if you want the table to float.

Comment: if you want to typeset a german document I recommend to use (additionally to `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` which you already have): `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` for being able to insert umlaute directly, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` for being able to copy and paste umlaute from the pdf and hyphenate words containing umlaute and `\usepackage{lmodern}` because the font used by T1 fontenc looks not so nice and ligatures could not be copied and pasted from the pdf.

Comment: I think, you should change the title of this question, as you wanted to have lines in your table, don't you?

Comment: @Jan how can i alternate colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution using `cmidrule` from `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,fleqn]{article} 
\usepackage[left=30mm,right=40mm,top=25mm,bottom=20mm, includeheadfoot]    
     {geometry}%centering hinter headfoot
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[rm={tabular, lining}, sf={tabular, lining},
             tt={monowidth, tabular, lining}]{cfr-lm}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}     
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage{courier}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %Schriftart geändert
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
\multicolumn{8}{l}{Data set-1 for the example problem}\\
\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Job}\\
 Stage & Machine & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$n=1$} & 
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{$n=2$}\\
 \cmidrule(lr){3-5}\cmidrule(l){6-8}
 $i$ & $m$ & 
 $S_{m,i,n,0}$ & $S_{m,i,n,1}$ & $S_{m,i,n,2}$ &  
 $S_{m,i,n,0}$ & $S_{m,i,n,1}$ & $S_{m,i,n,2}$ \\
 \midrule
   1& 1&40&15&60&30&70&10\\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{default}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much, i try to work with that =)

Comment: is there a way to combine the line under n=1 and n=2 to one line ?

Comment: @MiloLi: Yes, replace `\cmidrule(lr){3-5}\cmidrule(l){6-8}` by `\cmidrule{3-8}`. You can also read `booktabs` documentation to understand how options like `(lr)` change the result.

Comment: These are new questions. You can start them and make reference to this one. In any case I think you already found them answered here after a little search.

Comment: i found the asnwers! but can you tell me how do i put my table in colors like grey and white? i just see rows and colors in other examples, but how can i put complete stage 1 in table 1 in grey?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question yesterday and the answer was the hhline package in my case.

So it may help you too:

```
\usepackage{hhline}
%% ...

\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccc}
 \multicolumn{7}{l}Data set-1 for the example problem}\\ \hline
 1& \
  1&0&&&1&4&&1&6\ \\
 \hhline{~----------}
  1& \
  1&0&&&1&4&&1&6\
  \end{tabular}
```

[image]

~ is for no line at that column
- is for a line at that column

there should be as much chars as in the tabular definition itself.

---

**[edit]**

This gets closer to your initial example. The vertical rules are just to demonstrate the centering of the multi column cells.

```
   \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccc}
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{Data set-1 for the example problem}\\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{job}\\
        Stage & Mashine & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{n = 1} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{n = 2}\\
% Data set-1 for the example problem\\
 %\midrule
 \hhline{~~---------}
 1& \
 1&0&22222222&3&1&4&5&1&6&6\ \\ \hline
 1& \
 1&00000000&2&3&111111111111&4&5555555555&1&6&6 \\
  \end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: i get an error when i build in your features.

Comment: ! Missing \cr inserted.

Comment: I see, I put \hhline at the wrong position, I update the answer.